# Using index with range type query and other criteria

Tags: mysql, indexing

I need help with this. I have such query:

```
SELECT * FROM cart WHERE
(ts_in between 1249077600 AND 1318975199);
```

The above query is using btree index on ts_in colomn (range type). Now I want to add another criteria to this. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM cart WHERE
(ts_in between 1249077600 AND 1318975199) and is_removed=0;
```

The above query doesn't use the btree index on ts_in colomn (range).

Can somebody tell me why and how can I do it right way to reach very fast calculations.

I created two indexes for testing :

```
CREATE INDEX range_idx_1 using BTREE
ON cart (is_removed, ts_in);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX range_idx_2 using BTREE
ON cart (ts_in , is_removed);
```

What is Funny that when I use this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM cart WHERE
(ts_in between 1249077600 AND 1318975199) AND is_removed=0;
```

I receive this results:

```
id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys           | key         | key_len | ref | rows  | Extra 
1  | SIMPLE      | cart  | range | range_idx_1,range_idx_2 | range_idx_1 | 6       |     | 17391 | Using where; Using index
```

The above query is using index but:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM cart WHERE
(ts_in between 1249077600 AND 1318975199) AND is_removed=0;
```

I have such results:

```
id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys           | key         | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra 
1  | SIMPLE      | cart  | ref   | range_idx_1,range_idx_2 | range_idx_1 | 1       | const | 77979 | Using where
```

This doesn't use the index.

When I try to USE INDEX or FORCE INDEX syntax the results are the same. In one case Mysql doesn't use index. Any Help?

Comment: Please post the explain plan for each query.

Comment: Is it a MyISAM or an InnoDB table? Shall I guess that it is InnoDB ?

Comment: I added execution plan for each of the above scenario. It seems that the second query is not type range but why?

Comment: @ypercube It's a InnoDB table

Comment: That's why (because it's InnoDB) that is using the `(is_removed, ts_in)` index when you do `SELECT id ...`. The Primary Key is stored inside every index in InnoDB so MySQL does not have to read the table, only to range scan the index, to find the ids.

Comment: @ypercube So How can I fetch the data using indexes where I have to use in where one BETWEEN and one = (is_removed=0). Do You have any sugesstions. I must have InnoDB engine on this table.

Comment: If the optimizer thinks that the index should be used, it will use it. The `(is_removed, ts_in)` is probably the best you could have. Try it with `between 1249077600 AND 1249078000` to see that it will be used, even with the `SELECT * ...`.

Comment: I mean that sometimes it's better not to use any index, when selecting a large percent of the table (large being more than 5-10%, depending on various other factors).

Comment: @ypercube So thank You very much. This table contains about 30000 rows. Why the explain plan for second scenario show me in rows colomn 77979 value. When I use Your paremeters only one difrence is that the type of query is changed to range type but in Extra i get only USING WHERE without USING INDEX. I tried many parameters and diffrent configurations of thos parameters.

Comment: Can you run `ANALYZE TABLE cart` and then try again the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED query` and post again?

Answer (score 1):

run a

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM cart WHERE
(ts_in between 1249077600 AND 1318975199) and is_removed=0;
```

to see why the mysql query optimizer chooses a different index.

Mysql is not very good at combining indexes itself, so you probably will need a combined index for this query. Try to add a index (btree?) for `is_removed, ts_in` (in this order!).

You can also force mysql to use your index by adding a USE INDEX  to your query. Sometimes this gives better result as the index the query optimizer chose:

```
SELECT * FROM cart USE INDEX '<idx_name>' WHERE
(ts_in between 1249077600 AND 1318975199) and is_removed=0;
```

Comment: I fill the question with some more information. The USE INDEX or FORCE INDEX donesn't work. When I have in this query "select *" the mysql doesn't use index. When I have "select id" for example then mysql is using right index but I need the solution for "select *".

Comment: The 'id' is stored (I assume id is the primary key) in the index, so mysql doesn't need to access the table itself for generating the result set. But for select * it needs to, and the query optimizer comes to the conclusion using the index doesn't make any sense in this case. For '*' I think you will be out of luck doing it the simple way. Maybe some sort of cascading queries will work...